# How representative would attitudinal data of a small-n minority group (e.g. where N=20) be from a larger randomly sampled population?

Tags: sampling

Working with ANES data; N=4,271. Unfortunately, and the group was undersampled (N=20).

Answer (score 0):

The representativeness of a sample doesn't depend on its size but on whether it is a random sample from the population. A smaller random sample will have a larger standard error, but both would be unbiased.